# Simperium Data Dictionary or Decoder Ring for Return Value on "all" call?

Tags: html, ruby, return-value, simperium

I've looked through all of the Simperium API docs for all of the different programming languages and can't seem to find this. Is there any documentation for the data returned from an ".all" call (e.g. `api.todo.all(:cv=>nil, :data=>false, :username=>false, :most_recent=>false, :timeout=>nil)` )?

For example, this is some data returned:

```
{"ccid"=>"10101010101010101010101010110101010",
"o"=>"M",
"cv"=>"232323232323232323232323232",
"clientid"=>"ab-123123123123123123123123",
"v"=>{
     "date"=>{"o"=>"+", "v"=>"2015-08-20T00:00:00-07:00"},
     "calendar"=>{"o"=>"+", "v"=>false},
     "desc"=>{"o"=>"+", "v"=>"<p>test</p>\r\n"},
     "location"=>{"o"=>"+", "v"=>"Los Angeles"},
     "id"=>{"o"=>"+", "v"=>43}
     },
"ev"=>1,
"id"=>"abababababababababababababab/10101010101010101010101010110101010"}
```

I can figure out some of it just from context or from the name of the key but a lot of it is guesswork and trial and error. The one that concerns me is the value returned for the "o" key. I assume that a value of "M" is modify and a value of "+" is add. I've also run into "-" for delete and just recently discovered that there is also a "! '-'" which is also a delete but don't know what else it signifies. What other values can be returned in the "o" key? Are there other keys/values that can be returned but are rare? Is there documentation that details what can be returned (that would be the most helpful)?

If it matters, I am using the Ruby API but I think this is a question that, if answered, can be helpful for all APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The response you are seeing is a list of all of the changes which have occurred in the given bucket since some point in its history. In the case where `cv` is blank, it tries to get the full history.

You can find some of the details in [the protocol documentation](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-protocol/blob/master/SYNCING.md#index-change-version-cv) though it's incomplete and focused on the WebSocket message syntax (the operations are the same however as with the HTTP API).

The information provided by the `v` parameter is the result of applying the [JSON-diff](http://simperium.github.io/jsondiff/jsondiff-js.html) algorithm to the data between changes. With this diff information you can reconstruct the data at any given version as the changes stream in.